# remote debugging jython script runned by java program with eclipse and Pydev

Tags: pydev

I am trying to debug a jython script which runs via a java project. I have installed pydev in my eclipse IDE and I followed these instructions(http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html). when I am running the java app while python debug server is running  debugger recognizes normally that the jython script is going to be executed halt the excecution and wait for step over or resume commands.

The problem is that PyEdit(editor window) does not highlight the lines which are executed. Also debugger does not know the breakpoints of the scripts. It seems like debugger can not correlate the running thread with the script file.

Is there any way to configure pydev server to correlate debugging with a specific file?

Comment: Is that an exec'ed script or is that an imported script? How are you doing that integration (calling Jython from java)?